# First Order differential linear equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The given is 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+y=e^{3x}$$
Using $\mu$ as the integration factor we get
$$\mu=e^{\int{dx}}=e^x$$
Then multiplying n=both sides by $\mu$ we get

$$e^x\frac{dy}{dx}+e^xy=e^{4x}$$
Integrating both sides is easy enough 
$$ye^x=\frac{1}{4}e^{4x}$$
But the final answer should be $$y=\frac{1}{4}e^{3x}+Ce^{-x}$$ Did I pick the right $\mu$ or was there some other error I made.

Comment: you mean $e^{2x}$ not $e^4x$

Comment: How can $e^x *e^x=e^{4x}$ ?

Comment: Did you write the correct DE because the provided answer is not the wright one

Comment: Sorry, It was meant to be $e^{3x}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the correct differential equation is :
$$y'+y=e^{3x}$$
$$(ye^x)'=e^{4x}$$
$$ye^x=\frac 1 4e^{4x}+C$$
$$y(x)=\frac 1 4e^{3x}+Ce^{-x}$$